# how to generate TFS 2010 detailed build steps report

Tags: tfs-reports

Are there out-of-the-box TFS 2010 reports that shows the detailed build steps taken?

If there's none, Is it possible to create one?

Answer (score 0):

When you click on the `View Log` link on the Build Explorer, you get a detailed log of the build process. You can also see the MSBuild log by clicking `View Log File` link under the Summary section.

[image: build log]

[TFS process templates](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=80608) comes also with out-of-the-box SSRS reports such as `Build Success Over Time` and `Build Summary` ([Scrum](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/59ac03e3-df99-4776-be39-1917cbfc5d8e)) and `Build Summary Report` ([Agile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380647.aspx))

Comment: Thanks for your reply KMoraz.  Are there any SSRS report taht shows the steps contained in your screenshot?  when you have a very large steps, it takes time to read and load all the steps (log) in "View Log" link,  I wonder if there's SSRS that shows theses steps/logs

Comment: I'm not aware of an OOTB report that drills down to build steps. Build reports provides metrics and high level data. While you can customize your own SSRS report by parsing the build log into data grids, I don't think it's worth the effort - build administrators should be able to read build logs they way they are.